# PyDev Eclipse Invalid rectangle passed

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have installed Pydev plugin in eclipse, but when I trying to open any *.py I the eclipse stop and I get the next error

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

Anybody Could help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the problem in Eclipse RCP Neon1 under Ubuntu and GTK 3.
Fixed it by 2 lines in eclipse.ini (on the top of file):

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem was the result of this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435948

which has been fixed here:
https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/commit/?id=5630a091774a79a8abc13251bc46b8a2be1f6f8c

You can try using this version of Eclipse. It worked for me.

Comment: Just for information: Your link seems to be a work-around for Eclipse. I have the same problem in a non-eclipse related Python + Gtk program.

Comment: This is reported as the libpixman-1-0:amd64 problem. See here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=728678